# Flutter "infinite_scroll_pagination" plugin, when pull-to-refresh response data items are duplicating

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

I am new in flutter. When I'm Pull-to-Refresh the items should be load without duplicating previous loaded items. Anyone can help me? Thank you very much. I am new in flutter. When I'm Pull-to-Refresh the items should be load without duplicating previous loaded items. Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

```
class _AdListSliverGridState extends State<AdListSliverGrid> {
  final AdListSliverGridBloc _bloc = AdListSliverGridBloc();

  final PagingController<int, AdListSummary> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);
  late StreamSubscription _blocListingStateSubscription;
  bool _isLoadingStarted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _bloc.onPageRequestSink.add(pageKey);
    });

    _blocListingStateSubscription =
        _bloc.onNewListingState.listen((listingState) {
      _pagingController.value = PagingState(
        nextPageKey: listingState.nextPageKey,
        error: listingState.error,
        itemList: listingState.itemList,
      );
    });
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) async {
      if ((_pagingController.value.status == PagingStatus.loadingFirstPage ||
              _pagingController.value.status == PagingStatus.ongoing) &&
          _isLoadingStarted) return;
      _isLoadingStarted = true;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _refreshList() async {
    setState(() {
      _pagingController.refresh();
    });
    print('Refresh....');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    _blocListingStateSubscription.cancel();
    _bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _refreshList,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            PagedSliverGrid<int, AdListSummary>(
              pagingController: _pagingController,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: 0.810,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5,
              ),
              builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<AdListSummary>(
                itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => AdListGridItem(
                  adlist: item,
                  press: () {
                   
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use once this method : addPageRequestListener in initState

```
pageController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
  bloc.fetchNewPage(pageKey);
  // in here call your server request like code below:
}
```

in bloc:

```
Future<void> fetchNewPage(int pageKey) async {
try {
  final newItems = await getProject(pageKey); // this is api call with page key

  final isLastPage = newItems.length < ApiService.MAX_PER_PAGE;
if (isLastPage) { // this is a variable in your bloc that start with false
  pageController.appendLastPage(newItems);
} else {
  final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
  pendingPagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
}
} catch (error) {

}
```

}

**_refreshList() in this method you don't need to setState and just call  _pagingController.refresh();**